# IIS 8 Application Initialization - warming up WCF services

Tags: iis-8, warm-up

We are currently using AppFabric Auto-Start feature for warming up applications that contain WCF web services.

Since this is the only AppFabric feature we are using and we are upgrading to IIS  8.0, we would like to use the Application Initialization instead.

1) Would be happy to know if there are any known differences between these solutions.

2) I was able to set up initialization for the example project: 
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization. But when I set the same settings for my WCF service there is no warmup. I think this is because the warmup is done by issuing a request to

```
   http://localhost/MyService/
```

and this doesn't actually reach the service. I need the warmup request to be done to

```
    http://localhost/MyService/Service.svc
```

is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your web.config:

```
<applicationInitialization>
  <add initializationPage="/Service.svc" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

> The < applicationInitialization > element specifies that web application initialization is performed proactively before a request is received. An application can start up more quickly if initialization sequences such as initializing connections, priming in-memory caches, running queries, and compiling page code are performed before the HTTP request is received. Application Initialization can start the initialization process automatically whenever an application is started. The application initialization does not necessarily make the initialization process run any faster; it starts the process sooner.
>   [Source](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/applicationinitialization)

[IIS 8.0 Application Initialization](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization#TOC301259899)

Comment: when I add the above tags that you have mentioned, what does it actually execute? the constructor of my Service object or what

Comment: This answer is a copy-paste of some lines from somewhere without required explanations. So within the context of this question it doesn't provide any information. -1