# WCF Service Warm Start with IISExpress

Tags: wcf, service, iis-express, warm-up

I'm building a WCF service that on startup (not first invocation) needs to monitor the filesystem for files to be updated. I have the service working however, I'm running into a problem where I can't get the WCF service to "warm up" on deployment and start doing its job. The only way I've been able to get the service to start is by directly poking it via one of its web methods.

I've followed the instructions in the following articles to no avail:

[IIS 8 Application Initialization - warming up WCF services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524612/iis-8-application-initialization-warming-up-wcf-services)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/508713/Custom-WCF-web-service-warm-up

The only difference between what I'm doing and the samples appears to be that I'm using IISExpress.  Has anyone had any success with WCF Service warm starts in IISExpress?

Dev Env: Visual Studio 2012 Sp2

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding concrete documentation on it, but I don't believe Auto Start / Warm Up is supported in IIS Express. Here is one blog post that says so, but is by no means canonical: http://t8462.codeinpro.us/q/508123784f1eba38a413f9cf